# String Search Operation in C

Tags: c, arrays, search, char

I want the value of the month index but the value of k is wrong. can cause? There is an error in the function but could not find it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 20
int get_month(const char *str, char *array[])
{

int k;
for (k = 0; k < 12; ++k)
    if (!strcmp(array[k], str)
    return k ;
return 0;
}
int main()
{
char s[SIZE];
char *months[] = {"January"," February","March", "April","May","June","July","August ","September", " October"," November","December" };
int result;
printf("enter the month : ");
gets(s);
result = get_month(s,months);
   if (result)
       printf("%s - %d.  is the month of the year.\n", s, result);
      else
    printf("%s invalid\n", s);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: in get_month, replace `months` with `array`.

Comment: Some of your strings have a space at the end but not all.

Comment: This code does not even compile.

Comment: What do you mean, "could not find it"? My compiler says `4: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers`, where `4` is a *line number*.

Comment: (After edit) **Read the compiler error messages**.

Answer (score 1):

```
int get_month(const char *str,int char **array)
                               ^
```

Clearly you should not have a `int` there, and a string array is best declared as `char*[]`
So it should be

```
int get_month(const char *str, char *array[])
```

And when you get the index, you should plus 1 to the answer because the index in C starts with 0 but human counts from 1. You also have some spaces in the string constants too which would fail the `strcmp`.

---

Full working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 20
int get_month(const char *str, char **array){

    int k;
    for (k = 0; k < 12; ++k)
        if (!strcmp(array[k], str))
            return k+1 ;
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    char s[SIZE];
    char *months[] = {"January","February","March", "April","May","June","July","August","September", "October","November","December" };
    int result;
    printf("enter the month : ");
    gets(s);
    result = get_month(s,months);
    if (result)
        printf("%s - %d.  is the month of the year.\n", s, result);
    else
        printf("%s invalid\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Check here: [Coliru Sample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50c3a2d9e4ee45a3)

Comment: input enter the month :october ----> output : invalid @texasbruce

Comment: @user3718043: 1. `october` is invalid because it is spelled "October" in your array. 2. `october` is invalid because there is a space before it in your array.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, gets is deprecated now, use `fgets` instead.
The captured `string` is terminated with a new line character so any raw comparison will fail.

Secondly, `strcmp` returns an `integer`, not a `boolean`. And some elements in the list have spaces in it.

I reworked it to working program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MONTHS_ARRAY_LENGTH     (12)

static const char *months[MONTHS_ARRAY_LENGTH] =
{
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August ",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December"
};

static int get_month_number(const char *month_mbs)
{
    int month_nb = -1;

    for (int idx = 0; idx < MONTHS_ARRAY_LENGTH; ++idx) {
        if (strcasecmp(months[idx], month_mbs) == 0) {
            month_nb = idx + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return (month_nb);
}

int main(void)
{
    int result = 0;
    char s[21] = {0};

    printf("Enter a month: ");

    if (fgets(s, 20, stdin) == NULL) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Get rid of new line character captured by fgets. */
    for (int idx = 0; idx < 21; ++idx) {
        if (!isalpha(s[idx])) {
            s[idx] = '\0';
        }
    }

    result = get_month_number(s);
    if (result < 0) {
        printf("%s is an invalid argument.\n", s);

    } else {
        char a[3] = {0};

        switch (result) {
        case 1:  a[0] = 's'; a[1] = 't'; break;
        case 2:  a[0] = 'n'; a[1] = 'd'; break;
        case 3:  a[0] = 'r'; a[1] = 'd'; break;
        default: a[0] = 't'; a[1] = 'h'; break;
        }

        printf("%s is the %d%s month of the year.\n",
               s, result, a);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Well in C integers are used as boolean since there is no such type